# Can we extract the signal back after convolution with orthogonal code?

Tags: convolution, signal-processing, deconvolution

Assume we have a random signal $h$ convoluted with another signal $s$ which is assumed to be Walsh code represented by one column of Hadamard-matrix, i.e.,

$$s = \begin{bmatrix} 1\\ -1\\ -1\\ 1\end{bmatrix}$$

which means that all code of Walsh are have the same amplitude but they are only different in their sign. If we have $$x = h * s$$ where $*$ denotes convolution, is it possible to  estimate $h$ based on $x$?

here is an example:

$$h = \begin{bmatrix} 0.84\\ 1.24\\ 1.742\\ 0.012\end{bmatrix}$$

and

$$s = \begin{bmatrix} 1\\ -1\\ -1\\ 1\end{bmatrix}$$

Hence $x = h*s = :$

$$x = \begin{bmatrix} 0.84\\ 0.40\\ -0.3380\\ -2.13\\ -0.5140\\ 1.73\\ 0.0120
\end{bmatrix}$$

So, how can we solve $x$ in order to get $h$ based on $x$ ?

Thank you very much in advance.

Comment: @RodrigodeAzevedo I try providing mathematical notation, but when I don't know how to write it mathematically, I write it in MATLAB in order just to simplify understanding it.

Comment: @RodrigodeAzevedo I tried now to format it either to mathematics or MATLAB code as you recommended.  thank you for your advise

Comment: @RodrigodeAzevedo ..I hope it's ok now. . .  and sorry for that.

Comment: Take a look at [this](https://dsp.stackexchange.com/a/44439/21075).

Comment: @RodrigodeAzevedo Thank you for editing the question, it's ok. Regarding the length of x,  it's known following the convolution of any signals, it should be  length(h)+length(s)-1 , Thank you again.

Comment: You observe $\ell + 4 - 1$ samples and want to estimate $\ell$ samples. Looks like a least-squares problem to me.

Comment: @RodrigodeAzevedo Could you please explain more? I didn't understand what you mean.

Comment: Take a look at the answer I linked to above. In the end, you have a linear system of equations $A x = b$ and matrix $A$ appears to be tall.

Comment: @RodrigodeAzevedo , I think it's different about he example you have provided above. I have added an example in the question in order to clarify the case I'm talking about.  thank you

Comment: Convolution corresponds to multiplication by a Toeplitz matrix. You have a linear system $A x = b$.

Comment: @RodrigodeAzevedo  I got it, could you please explain that with few details as an answer in order to close the question.

Comment: I am not sure what is left to explain. You have a Toeplitz matrix $A$ and a vector $b$. You want to solve $A x = b$. If there are no solutions, try least-squares. If there are infinitely many solutions, try least-norm.

Comment: I mean to accept the answer and close the question

Comment: Oh, I see. Thank you. However, I think the comment section does already provide the answer.